# Rotating disk - pouring sand

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia

> A uniform disk of mass $M$ and radius $R$ is rotating freely about a vertical axis with initial angular velocity $\omega_0$. Then sand is poured onto the disk in a thin stream so that it piles up on the disk at the radius $r \lt R$. The sand is added at the constant rate $mu$ (mass per unit time). Find
>
> a) the angular acceleration of the disc as the sand falls down
>
>  b) the rate of rotational kinetic energy variation with time

I know that $L$ is conserved, but how can I calculate the moment of inertia (sand)? I wrote $\text{d}m = mu \text{d}t$, and then I got time in the integral and stopped because it doesn't give any information about time.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mass of the disk at $t\gt0$ is $ $ $m(t)=M+m_{u}.t$

at time t, $dm$ is added to the disk which is rotating with speed of $\omega(t)$. This dm, before landing on the disk, has no speed in parallel to the disk, so when it lands on the disk, its speed (parallel to the disk) changes from 0 to $r\omega$, so $F=dP/dt= dm.r\omega/dt=m_{u}.r.w $ (eq.1). Now, the reaction of this force $(-F)$ is exerted to the disk which creates a negative angular acceleration. $T=I.\alpha$ and $\alpha=d\omega/dt$, so $-F.r=I.d\omega/dt $ $   $ (eq.2).

(eq.1) and (eq.2) give us:

$-m_{u}.r^2.w=I. d\omega/dt$. You can solve this differential equation for $\omega(t)$.

For mass inertia of the disk $I$. Substitute $I=1/2 (M+m_{u}.t). R^2.$

Comment: Thank you very much! And sorry for this kind of question.